# Unlocking iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, unlock

I hope this doesn't go against the rules of the site. I have an iPhone 3G for which I did a restore without knowing it was unlocked as it originally came from the US (I'm in Mexico) I'd like to fix it since it isn't mine but I've tried redsn0w and blackra1n without luck =( could anyone please help me out? I feel really awful for rendering useless the iPhone of my friend...and I can't seem to fix it..it was firmware 3.1.3 it said it was upgrading but then it restored so I'm guessing the firmware didn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree - PwnageTool tends to be the best, most complete and safest form of jailbreaking because it modifies the iPhone's firmware on your computer and then transfers it to the phone during a restore through iTunes, as opposed to accepting a new iOS upgrade from Apple and then re-jailbreaking it on the device. Another benefit of PwnageTool is that it doesn't upgrade your iPhone's baseband, which means that once you're unlocked, as long as you only upgrade using PwnageTool, you'll stay unlockable.

[iClarified](http://iclarified.com/tutorials/iphone/) has excellent tutorials for unlocking and jailbreaking iPhones and a wizard to help you decide which tutorial to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to watch out for with iPhones is the baseband firmware -- there need to be both a jailbreak (allows unsigned applications like Cydia to run) and an unlock for your baseband firmware. At 3.1.3 you should be ok.

1. Jailbreak. Use whatever method works for you. I'd reccomend using the latest [PwnageTool](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/search/pwnagetool) from the official Dev Team links
2. Search in Cydia for an unlock and install the appropriate one.
3. ???
4. PROFIT!